# Could Touchpad-Indicator be conflicting with Dropbox?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, indicator, panel, dropbox

OK, I've done a fair bit of searching on this topic, and while I've found several similar situations, I can't find any information on my specific issue.

I'm running a relatively new/clean installation of 12.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad. I'm a low- to mid-level Ubuntu user; I'm comfortable playing around a little in the Terminal as long as I have fairly solid guidance. I have very little "extra" stuff installed; this is primarily an internet/email/LibreOffice machine.

One item that I absolutely love is touchpad-indicator from atareao-team. It does exactly what I want (disable the touchpad when I plug in a mouse, enable the touchpad when I unplug a mouse).

BUT, with touchpad-indicator, I cannot get Dropbox to work correctly. I have tried every Dropbox install workaround trick I can find, but no matter what, there's always a problem. The main issue is that I don't get the Dropbox icon or the accompanying menu, which makes it difficult to confirm whether or not I'm getting files. (I use a shared Dropbox account to share files between a number of fellow employees, so I don't always know if/when something is being changed or added.)

If I remove touchpad-indicator, then I can install Dropbox correctly.

While their functionality is completely different, they both rely on having a small menu in the panel, so my guess is that there's something causing a little conflict there.

Another side note, I also have an account with Copy, and that works just fine in the panel with either touchpad-indicator or Dropbox.

Surely, I'm not the only person attempting to use both touchpad-indicator and Dropbox? Any insight would be welcome.